# Print html file with CUPS

Tags: cups

Is there a way to explicitly tell the CUPS server that the file you are sending is `text/html` thus overriding the mime.types lookup?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is.

Use this commandline:

```
lp -d printername -o document-format=text/html file.html
```

---

#### Update (in response to comments)

I provided an exact answer to the OP's question.

However, this (alone) does not guarantee that the file will be successfully printed. To achieve that, CUPS needs a *filter* which can process the input of MIME type *`text/html`*.

Such a filter is not provided by CUPS itself. However, it is easy to plug your own filter into the CUPS filtering system, and some Linux distributions ship such a filter capable to consume HTML files and convert them to a printable format.

You can check what happens in such a situation on *your* system. The `cupsfilter` command is a helper utility to run available/installed CUPS filters without the need to do actual printing through the CUPS daemon:

```
touch 1.html
/usr/sbin/cupsfilter --list-filters 1.html
```

Now on a system with no HTML consuming filter ready, you'd get this response:

```
cupsfilter: No filter to convert from text/html to application/pdf.
```

On a different system (like on a Mac), you'll see this:

```
xhtmltopdf
```

You can even force input and output MIME types to see which filters CUPS would run automatically when asked to print this file an a printer supporting that particular output MIME type (**`-i`** sets the input MIME type, **`-m`** the output):

```
/usr/sbin/cupsfilter                  \
            -i text/html              \
            -m application/postscript \
            --list-filters            \
              1.html
  xhtmltopdf
  cgpdftops
```

Here it would first convert HTML to PDF using `xhtmltopdf`, then transform the resulting PDF to PostScript using `cgpdftops`.

If you skip the `--list-filters` parameter, the command would actually even go ahead and do the conversion by actively running (not just listing) the two filters and emit the result to *`<stdout>`*.

You could write your own CUPS filter based on a Shell script. The only other ingredient you need is a command line tool, such as `htmldoc` or `wkhtmltopdf,` which is able to process HTML input and produce some format that in turn could be consumed by the CUPS filtering chain further down the road.

Be aware, that some (especially JavaScript-heavy) HTML files cannot be successfully processed by simple command line tools into print-ready formats.

If you need more details about this, just ask another question...

Comment: What about lpr? Is it also possible?

Comment: @DIH: Of course: `lpr -P printername -o document-format=text/html file.html`

Comment: That's an interesting issue that I'm having then. On Mac OSX 10.9.1, the output from a printer when using your code is just a blank page. PDFs are printed perfectly, without the need to specify document-format, yet all and any HTML document come out blank.

Comment: @DIH: Can you post (a link to) your `file.html` then? (BTW, *usually* you never need to specify `document-format`, because CUPS will by default do an *auto-tying* of all received print files. But the question by the OP was: *how to explicitly override CUPS' built-in auto-typing function*, and that's what my answer told him...)

Comment: I also went to localhost:631, visited the finished printing jobs and attempted a reprint. It completed, but the printout was still a blank page. Printing the same HTML document using Cmd + P prints it properly.

Comment: Printing from commandline (`lp` or `lpr`) is very different from printing from a browser window (`[cmd] + [p]`): the first sends HTML into CUPS and relies on CUPS' auto-filtering system to convert HTML to the printer language of your printer. The second tells the browser to convert HTML to PostScript, and CUPS only ever sees PostScript arriving in its realm. Your CUPS system may not be able to really process HTML. (Try to force it as text printing, by saying `-o document-format=plain/text`...)

Comment: BTW, you do not need to insist on `lpr`. `lp` should also work, with identical results as `lpr`...

Comment: Advantage of `lp`: it prints the job's *request id* in the terminal, which `lpr` does not. You can use the request id to search for what's in the log: `grep "Job 331" /var/log/cups/error_log` and `grep "Job 331" /var/log/cups/error_log | grep -E '(filter|backend)'`...

Comment: The reason I sticked to lpr is because lp with the same parameters is throwing `lp: Bad page-ranges values 0-0.` my way. Specifying `-o page-ranges=1` did not help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46004/discussion-between-dih-and-kurt-pfeifle)

Comment: lol.. prime example of people trying to hi-jack another users post.. Continue in chat... Nope ... ah that made my day

Comment: @PeterKandinsky: I've put an update into the answer.